How to openseadragon annotorious - openseadragon, fabricjs combination used?
Where openseadragon uses annotorious-openseadragon, how can I use it with fabricjs?I desperately need help。
Currently openseadragon is used with annotorious, but I would like to add fabricjs to extend the measurement and screenshot capabilities

Have you tried just adding the https://github.com/altert/OpenseadragonFabricjsOverlay plugin? Are you having trouble with it?
